# svg slideshow with ffmpeg

Tags: svg, ffmpeg

can anyone point out to me, how to make a slideshow (with ffmpeg) with svg images.
The usual way,

```
ffmpeg -i bloch_0%2d.svg bloch2.mp4
```

doesn't work since ffmpeg can't handle svg files obviously (Invalid data found when processing input) is there an easy way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Please include your complete ffmpeg console output that results from your command.

Comment: I strongly disagree with closing. I'm a programmer, and want to convert SVG/CSS animations output by an animation engine that I wrote: convert to video for colleagues whose browsers can't handle the SVGs. What I need would therefore count as "a software tool commonly used by (animation) programmers", and therefore be on-topic. What has closure achieved, other than denying me the answer which would probably have been posted had the question been left open? In essence, this is about converting data from one format to another: no more off-topic than e.g. a question about converting CSV to XLS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First convert the SVG images to a raster format, such as PNG or JPEG.  If your SVG editor does not support exporting to a raster format, this can be done using ImageMagick's `convert` command:

```
convert bloch_*.svg bloch_%03d.png
```

Note: For the best SVG support, ensure that ImageMagick was compiled to use the RSVG library.  [Details](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#svg)

Next, convert the raster images to H.264 in MP4 using `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i bloch_%03d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p bloch2.mp4
```

The `-r 1` option sets the frame rate of the input to 1 frame per second, but you can set it to whatever you like depending on whether these are independent images or a continuous animation of some sort.

The `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is not required, however PNG color is not subsampled.  H.264 video can support non-subsampled color with a specialized profile, but most players only support 4:2:0 color subsampling, so you will probably want to convert it to 4:2:0.  JPEG normally uses 4:2:0 so if your input is JPEG then you would not normally need this option.

Comment: The only thing with this is that the .pngs can take a lot more space than the SVGS.

Comment: @mark4o , do you have any idea for how to use ImageMagick in android?