# is it possible to put vector graphics into a video?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, video, vector-graphics

I want to have a video graphic output, something similar to svg or eps for images but for videos, is it possible with any language?

if it's impossible is there any way to write a file from svg images (program to show one svg image per second for example) ?

thanks

Comment: What about animated svg? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343476/there-is-a-web-standard-for-animated-vector-images

Comment: not really because I have near 1000 svg image files (frames from a video), and I want to combine these images into one file which behaves like a video

Comment: In case you want to create a video file look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118609/svg-slideshow-with-ffmpeg).

Comment: ffmpeg only uses raster format as output, i want to create vector video graphic slideshow, not in any raster classic format